# Proof subtraction is not forward stable

Tags: proof-verification, numerical-methods, fake-proofs

I've been taught that the "subtraction operation" is not accurate/forward stable as the relative error can be arbitrary large.

I tried to prove it formally but I end up with a contradiction.

**What I'm given**

In this question
we will consider the stability of some elementary operations using the “axioms” of computer arithmetic.
Thus we assume that

(P1): For all $x \epsilon \mathbb{R}$, there exists $\varepsilon$ with |$\varepsilon$| < $\varepsilon_m$ and $fl(x) \epsilon \mathbb{F}$ such that $fl(x) = x(1 + \varepsilon)$

(P2): For every elementary operation $∗$ and all $x, y \epsilon \mathbb{F}$, there exists $\varepsilon$ with $|\varepsilon|$ < $\varepsilon_m$ such that
$x 
∗' y = (x ∗ y)(1 + ε)$.

(Note $∗$ denotes the exact operation whereas $∗'$ represents the "computer arithmetic operation")

**My attempt**

We have $$f(x)=x_1-x_2$$ and

$$g(x)=x_1 -' x_2=x_1(1+\varepsilon_1)(1+\varepsilon_3)-x_2(1+\varepsilon_2)(1+\varepsilon_3)$$ with $|\varepsilon_1|,|\varepsilon_2|,|\varepsilon_3|$ $\lt$ $\varepsilon_m$

hence

$$\frac{|g(x)-f(x)|}{|f(x)|}=\frac{|x_1(\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_3+\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_3)-x_2(\varepsilon_2+\varepsilon_3+\varepsilon_2\varepsilon_3)|}{|x_1-x_2|}$$
And thus

$$\frac{|g(x)-f(x)|}{|f(x)|}< \frac{|(x_1-x_2)(2\varepsilon_m+\varepsilon_m^2)|}{|x_1-x_2|}<(2\varepsilon_m+\varepsilon_m^2)$$

which would show that subtraction is accurate.

There is obviously some mistake in my reasoning and I would be very grateful if someone could help me on that.

Comment: You majorized the difference in the numerator by majorizing each term. It is not true that $|3-1|<|5-4|$ even though $3<5$ and $1<4$.

Comment: Oooh, right I see. So can I just conclude with "as the difference x1-x2 is arbitrary small, the relative error of g(x) with respect to f(x) can be arbitrary  large and thus subtraction isn't forward stable" ?